# jedit alters user and group of file

Tags: alter, jedit

I'm running jedit as root, to alter several system files in /etc, some of these files
have different owners then root.

When I edit such a file, and save them, jedit set user to root and group to root.

Is there a option to set, that jedit keeps the file permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Turn off 2-stage save
2. Set the number of backups to 0, to disable them

The second step is not necessary on version 5.0, which will be released this year. This is the related bug report: [#1803073](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1803073&group_id=588&atid=100588)

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the backup version to 0

Answer (score 0):

From reading the [user guide](http://www.jedit.org/users-guide/saving.html) you could maybe try turning off two-stage save to see if this fixes the problem.

Comment: The option two-stage-save can be found in (jEdit 4.3.1):
Utilities->General Options->jEdit->Saving & Backup.


But this doesn't solve the problem, the the owner and group of the file are still reset to root root.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Changing ownership was not the biggest problem for me. It was that jEdit created a new file with 600 or 700 permissions. Apache couldn't read this file, so I had to chmod it again and again. Turning off 2-stage save and setting backups to 0 didn't solve my problem.

I installed jEdit 5, which keeps owner and permissions. For some reason Debian/Ubuntu still use 4.4, and adding the sourceforge deb line to the repository didn't work. In the end I downloaded 5 and installed it as root.